# pulseaudio - commands algorithm

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

I am watching the [example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Simultaneous_HDMI_and_analog_output) of simultaneous mode as :

```
### Load analog device
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
set-default-sink combined
```

And I don't get it how the first expression as `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0` is related to the second one as `load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined` or how exactly it works cause seems like the block really combines the build-in which is hw:0,0 and USB headphones which is hw:1,0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include a link to the example, but the example doesn't look very well thought out because

- On all distros I know `module-alsa-sink` gets automatically loaded by the rest of the configuration, you don't have to manually load it (verify by listing modules with `pacmd list-modules`)
- `module-combine-sink` comes with parameters which allow you to specify the sinks to combine, e.g.

  ```
  pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined sink_properties=device.description=myCombine slaves=sink1,sink2,sink3,sink4 channels=2
  ```

The module documentation with parameter description is [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/).

Possibly in whatever configuration the example assumed (you didn't link, so I can't tell...) `module-combine-sink` picks the right sinks by default, but that doesn't mean you should do it that way, and I'd consider it bad practice not to explictily name the slave sinks.

**Edit**

I don't know what the behaviour is when the `slaves` parameters is absent, and I don't really care: I'd have to read the code to find out, and I'm too lazy to do that. Just add the `slaves` parameter.

BTW, `hw:0,0` and `hw:1,1` are the ALSA names; you need to use the Pulseaudio names (see e.g. `pacmd list-sinks`) in the parameter.

The *default* sink is the sink that is used as output by default when a Pulseaudio application starts. That may or may not play a role in the behaviour when `slaves` is absent; as I said, I don't really care. :-)

There are no "hidden sinks". There may be ALSA devices where Pulseaudio hasn't created sinks (and sources) for that particular device, but as I said, on all distros that happens on startup.

Comment: OK :) I added the link to my question; I am not sure is the expression as `load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined` (expression B) combines all existing sinks or so? By fact I have two physical devices as plugged-in headphones (the build-in hw:0,0) and USB headset (hw:1,0); So the `expression B` combines all not even manually created sinks; But as you can see, I don't create sink manually  for (hw:1,0)'s device but still (?thanks to expression B) it is also combined to hw:0,0 one ? So there are some default and hidden sinks?

Comment: So if not to use the slaves argument then it combines all plugged-in audio devices or? Please give more details

Comment: I don't know what happens if you do not use the `slaves` argument. I would either have to experiment (and so can you) or read the source code (and so can you) to find out. But it's a waste of time to do that, because for all meaningful applications, you want to combine specific sinks, so you *know* which sink names you want to use, and just use the `slaves` argument with those sink names. Problem solved.